# Make an API call in a React functional component with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an API call to the backend with the click of a button in ReactJs. I have found 3 ways that I can do that by reading stackoverflow, tutorials and articles.

1. Add a simple function inside or outside the functional component that will make the API call (found many tutorials that use this method)
2. Add a state variable that when changed, it will trigger the useEffect hook (with dependency to the state variable) that will make the API call
3. Add a useCallback hook on a function and call that to make the API call

My thoughts are that the 1st is easy, simple but is it correct? And the 3rd might be wrong because you are not using the useCallback as intended (passing it to a child component and prevent re-rendering)
Which way is correct (if there is another way please suggest) and why?

Comment: Option 1 is fine. 2 is weird. 3 is fine too, if you need to.

Comment: Option 1 definitely works, but I'd disagree with @AKX that 2 is weird. It's a common process used with React apps to re-render the component with new data once the data is loaded, and during the request possibly display a loading indicator.

Comment: @code I wouldn't trigger the API call with a state variable. You could set a "loading" state in the API call effect though.

Comment: @AKX you might have gotten it reversed. The state doesn't trigger the API call; the API call triggers the state.

Comment: @code That's how I read "Add a state variable that when changed, it will trigger the useEffect hook"...

Comment: @AKX well, sorry, I read it wrong, my bad. I do believe that the OP did mean vice versa though, or it'll be completely senseless for general usage.

Comment: No worries. Hence "weird" ;-)

Comment: That is what I meant. The useEffect has a dependancy on a state variable, and when the state variable is changed (by the click of a button) then the useEffect makes the API call. I think I would prefer the 1st option but I didn't know if it was considered correct. I saw somewhere that API calls and effects should always be in the useEffect hook

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a simple API call, I would go for option 1.
Option 2 seems to me too "big" for a simple API call.